# List gives 500 error when trying to query via REST endpoint SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I've got a list on my site that I'm trying to query via REST:

```
https://mysite/sites/division/office/program/subprogram/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Taskers')/items
```

I can confirm the list exists, and I have checked that the title is correct.I have tried changing the query to query by GUID instead of title, and I still get the same error. There are no calculated columns in the list. I can query other lists in the same site and return results successfully. Any ideas of what I should look for to troubleshoot this problem further? I will add that this site was recently migrated from SP 2010 to SP Online.

Comment: Try to add `$select=Title` and check if it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access the URL below to check if it works.

```
https://mysite/sites/division/office/program/subprogram/_api/web/lists
```

And check if you can find the "Taskers" list in the results.

If still not works, we can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to send a request and check the responses.

Comment: That did it- why it worked without it on other lists and not on this one is a mystery to me, but making sure to add the parameters after /items solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have a throttling issue. Does the list have more than 5000 items? If so, try to index a column.

```
List Settings --> Indexed Columns --> Create a new index --> select a column (even Title) --> OK
```